# How can I give focus to phpStorm after opening a file via explorer? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, phpstorm, explorer

When I double click on a file in my explorer in Windows 7 (and I have bound phpStorm as the default program to open this filetype), the file opens correctly in phpStorm, but the focus stays on my explorer window.

I would like to automatically switch to phpStorm after I opened a file from explorer (as is default with many other applications). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, please follow [IDEA-114634](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114634) for updates